# Gitlab validation using personal access token

Tags: api, gitlab, access-token, gitlab-api

I need to validate the personal access token for gitlab. I know we can use the `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?private_token=<token>` api to do so. But this api returns public projects when the `private_token` isn't specified.

I am looking at the scenario when the user does not have any associated projects to his name, and I need to validate his private token against gitlab.

Answer (score 3):

Could you somehow make use of the /personal_access_tokens api call (See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/personal_access_tokens.html)